# How to fix error "Invalid Token" with jwt?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

Here is my utils.js
I don't understand why the respond is "Invalid token".
My goal is to authenticate the token from existing user and create the neworder.

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const generateToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
    },
  `${process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY}`,
    {
      expiresIn: '30d',
    }
  );
};


export const isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const authorization = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authorization) {
    const token = authorization.slice(7, authorization.length); // Bearer XXXXXX
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decode) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(401).send({message: "Invalid Token" });
        console.log("authorization")
      } else {
        req.user = decode;
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ message: 'No Token' });
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I edited your post to do some cleanup. To learn why I did what I did, please read [ask], [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587), and [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: You posted a lot of code. Is this the shortest possible example program that reproduces the problem? Please read the instructions on how to provide a [mre].

Comment: If you would log `err` and `token` and show them  here, it would be easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: Hey jps my token is Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2M2FlMDdjMDQ3ZmQ5NWEzMTgwNDJhNTMiLCJuYW1lIjoia2V2aW4ga3V0b3lpIiwiZW1haWwiOiJrZXZpbmt1dG95aTk1QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlzQWRtaW4iOmZhbHNlLCJpYXQiOjE2NzIzNDk2MzIsImV4cCI6MTY3NDk0MTYzMn0.ij6io2sjwms0MoMUHpE9JJfI8ELbZSNHDX4j711XWTI

Comment: also err
: 
{name: "JsonWebTokenError", message: "invalid signature"}

Answer (score 0):

In one function you use `JWT_SECRET_KEY` but in the other you use `JWT_SECRET`   For a presumably symmetric secret you should be using the same value.

Comment: After checking that I keep getting this err:   err : {name: "JsonWebTokenError", message: "invalid signature"}

Answer (score 0):

You are right! The function names have to be the same.

I have found the solution to this error.

It was because in my previous jwt token function i changed it to
`${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`

And I was using it directly which led to the error
process.env.JWT_SECRET

So instead of process.env.JWT_SECRET in the added function for isAuth,
use this to reference JWT Secret ie `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`

Comment: *You are right!* - who is right? - *It was because in my previous jwt token function i changed...* - sounds like you are the OP (with a second account)